# Running PhpStorm with Docker on Win 8.1: Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server

Tags: docker, phpstorm, docker-machine

I have just started with docker and set up Docker Toolbox on Win 8.1. I have tried it out, created some Cotainers and played with those a bit. Works fine.

Now I want to use PhpStorm to create a new Project that runs in Docker. Therefore I created a new project and created a very simple docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'    
services:
  webserver:
    image: phpstorm/php-71-apache-xdebug-26
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    environment:
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=host.docker.internal
```

I have started my default docker machine and then try starting this file in PhpStorm. Then I get this message: "**Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server.**"

I tried to google this error and nothing really fits my problem. I tried adding

```
"InsecureRegistry": [
                "192.168.99.100:5000"
            ],
```

to the config.json of my default machine. I also tried port 80.

Here is a screenshot of what I'm doing and seeing: 
https://paste.pics/7QSJS

Any hints? Thanks

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by `then try starting this file in PhpStorm`, what exactly you do, what you get as a result (if it's a browser window, please share the URL) and where this message appears

Comment: sorry @EugeneMorozov, I didnt know there were differnet approaches to this., I'm simply starting the docker container attached to the php storm project, see this screenshot for more info. Thanks https://paste.pics/7QSJS

Comment: Does running `docker-compose up -d` in Terminal start the service? Also, please share a screenshot of the run configuration itself, like [this](http://prntscr.com/qnlor7) one

Comment: @EugeneMorozov I tried it and it returned
`ERROR: The Compose file '.\docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:Unsupported config option for services: 'webserver'`
so I added `version: '3'` as first line and that helped. now manually invoking works. But in PHPStorm I still get "Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server."

As for the run config: https://paste.pics/7QT5V

Comment: This is Docker for Windows, right? Did you check [this](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/91/a5/docker-for-windows-tls-enable.png) checkbox and set the port accordingly in PhpStorm?

Comment: No, i dont have a gui in docker toolbox. But you post made me check the config json of my docker machine and I thought about the ports again. since docker-machin sits on port 2376 i added this to the `InsecureRegistry` setting. Now docker prompted me to regenerate my certs via `docker-machine regenerate-certs [machine-name]`which i did. And that worked! I am now connected to docker via PhpStorm. Thanks for sticking with me through this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the default docker toolbox port in windows helped fix the problem.

```
"InsecureRegistry": [
                "192.168.99.100:2376"
            ],
```

After that I also had to regenerate the certs via

```
docker-machine regenerate-certs [machine-name]
```

Comment: Hi. I have the same problem.
I added `"InsecureRegistry": ["192.168.99.100:2376"],` in config.json HostOptions - EngineOptions - InsecureRegistry, But still not working
Can you help me?